# How to delete a whole line from a text file from the input entered

Tags: java, file

i'm trying to delete a whole line after entering the Association Name but isnt working. it keeps showing the error, could not delete original input file can you please help me with this?

```
String inputFileName = "Association Record.txt";
String outputFileName = "Association Report.txt";
String lineToRemove = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Association Name to Delete the Record");

try{
          File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
          File outputFile = new File(outputFileName);

          try{
                  BufferedReader r1= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
                  BufferedWriter w1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));   
                  String line = null;
                                while ((line = r1.readLine()) != null) {
                                        if (!line.equals(lineToRemove)) {
                                            w1.write(line);
                                            w1.newLine();
                                        }
                                }//end while
           }
                    catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}  
                    if (inputFile.delete()) {
                            if (!outputFile.renameTo(inputFile))
                                            throw new IOException("Could not rename " + outputFileName + " to " + inputFileName);
                            }
                    else {throw new IOException("Could not delete original input file " + inputFileName);}      
                }
                catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
}
```

example of one of the line in the file:
COMPUTER,pc,08/07/2018,brandon

*COMPUTER is the association name

Comment: First you need to add `flush()` and `close()` after the write operation

Comment: still doesn't work after i add it

Comment: You need add more information describe what's doesn't work

Comment: it still shows the error, "could not delete original input file ....." after i add the flush() and close() after the write operation

Comment: After the **while** loop: `r1.close(); w1.close();`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd i've done it, the error doesnt show anymore but it still doesnt delete the line in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the word **COMPUTER** is the association word and the line you want to delete **starts with** the word **COMPUTER** then the **String#equals()** method is not the one to use in your **IF** statement. You would want to use the [String#startsWith()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_startswith.htm) method, for example:

```
boolean ignoreLetterCase = true;  // ignore Letter Case by default
String lineToRemove = "computer";
String criteria = ignoreLetterCase ? lineToRemove.toLowerCase() : lineToRemove;

while ((line = r1.readLine()) != null) {
    String procString = ignoreLetterCase ? line.toLowerCase : line;
    if (!procString.startsWith(criteria)) {
        w1.write(line);
        w1.newLine();
    }
}
```

The file data line `COMPUTER,pc,08/07/2018,brandon` will not be written to the destination file.

If however you want to ignore a file line that **contains** the associative word **COMPUTER** ***anywhere*** within a retrieved data line then you will want to utilize the [String#contains()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm) method, for example:

```
boolean ignoreLetterCase = true;  // ignore Letter Case by default
String lineToRemove = "computer";
String criteria = ignoreLetterCase ? lineToRemove.toLowerCase() : lineToRemove;

while ((line = r1.readLine()) != null) {
    String procString = ignoreLetterCase ? line.toLowerCase : line;
    if (!procString.contains(criteria)) {
        w1.write(line);
        w1.newLine();
    }
}
```

The file data line `COMPUTER,pc,08/07/2018,brandon` will **not** be written to the destination file. However a file data line which contains `PRINTER,pc-computer,09/27/2018,joseph` will also **not** be written to the destination file since the word **computer** is contained within the original file line.

I highly doubt this will ever be the case with your data file but if a retrieved file data line **only** contains the associative word (COMPUTER) then by all means you would want to use the [String#equals()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equals.htm) or [String#equalsIgnoreCase()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equalsignorecase.htm) method.

If you want to ignore original file lines where the associative word is only pertinent within a specific data column of any retrieved file data line then you would want to parse (split) each line into a columnar data array and do your comparisons on the desired column (array elemental index). For example:

```
// Delete all file lines where the NAME column equals 
// the name 'brandon' or 'Brandon' or 'BRANDON'.

boolean ignoreLetterCase = true;  // ignore Letter Case by default  
int deleteIfInColumn = 3;
String nameToDelete = "Brandon"; 
String criteria = ignoreLetterCase ? nameToDelete .toLowerCase() : nameToDelete;

while ((line = r1.readLine()) != null) {
    String procString = ignoreLetterCase ? line.toLowerCase : line;
    String[] columnData = procString.split(",");
    if (columnData[deleteIfInColumn].equals(criteria)) {
        continue;  // Skip to next file line
    }
    w1.write(line);
    w1.newLine();
}
```